# Different ways of declaring function type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I find in typescript you can simply declare a function type using `declare` keyword, for example:

```js
declare function test1(name: string): true

const t1 = test1('t') // true
```

and i can also do this using the arrow notation:

```js
const test2 = (name: string) => true

const t2 = test2('t') // boolean
```

Both of them works fine without any compiler error. But it seems like the final inferred type is different even i specific them to be `true` at the same time?

Meanwhile, if i change the return type `true` to a general primitive type, for example `string`, the second example will give me an error:

```js
declare function test1(name: string): string // ok

const test2 = (name: string) => string // error: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

It looks like for the "arrow function notation" type, you have to specify the return result/type to be a specific result, for example, generic does not make sense as well if you put it into the final result:

```js
declare function test1<T>(name: T): T // ok

const test2 = <T>(name: T) => T // error: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

However, both of them does not **"looks like a type"**, what i mean this is you are able to define them using `const` keyword(in second example, usually this is for declaring a variable from my knowledge), and you can then call them like a normal function, it will give you the return type/result without implement the actual detail:

```js
test1('xxx')
test2('xxx')
```

So my question would be:

- Are they real a type(like type alias)? Do they have actual names in typescript?
- Is there any difference between those two notations? How could we use them properly?

Comment: The first one doesn't ACTUALLY create a function `test1` - executing it will fail. `declare` makes the compiler just assume this will come from *somewhere* without verifying where from. If it doesn't, then you won't get an error at compile time.

Comment: Reading more of the question, you seem to be confused between what an arrow function is and a function signature is. when you do `declare function test1(name: string): true` you say that there *is* a function (somewhere) that matches the description: the name is `test1`, it takes a single parameter which is a string and it *always returns true*. When you do an arrow function you *create* a function and then TS *infers the type* of it. So, it constructs an entry that is similar to what you have in the `declare`. The signature and the function itself are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `declare` something, it just tells the TypeScript compiler that there will be that function/variable/class etc. at runtime and is removed during compilation. You specify the *type* (or function signature for a function) of that thing:

```
// these are the same
declare function test1(name: string): true
declare const test1: (name: string) => true
test1('') // true
```

What you did with `test2` is you created an arrow function that will exist at runtime because you didn't use the `declare` keyword and provided the implementation:

```
// these are also the same
function test2(name: string) {
  return true
}
const test2 = (name: string) => true
test2('') // boolean
```

As the return type is not explicitly stated, TypeScript infers the return type to be of `boolean`. To specify that it is `true`:

```
function test3(name: string): true {
  return true
}
const test3 = (name: string): true => true
test3('') // true
```

Comment: Thanks. I think i just asked a extremely stupid question. `const test2 = (name: string) => true` is actually the implementation not type definition. Anyway appreciate with your detailed explanation.